# Can't change bundle ID in itunes connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

my first app got rejected because it has the word Youtube in the bundle ID. I've since then changed the bundle ID in the plist.info and in the bundle identifier in Xcode. I also create a new app id under the identifier section in the member center of Apple's developer site but when i try to change it in the EDIT APP INFORMATION section in itunes connect, there is no drop down menu so i can't choose the new bundle ID i made without the word youtube in it. It is because my app is in status "Waiting for upload"? Here what i want to change "Bundle ID" in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: You cannot change the bundle id, as far as I know. You should create a new app in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html, the Bundle ID "can’t be edited after the app is approved."

So, if you have app has previously been approved, then you can't change your Bundle ID. But, if your app has NEVER been approved, then you should be able to change your Bundle ID.

I think your issue is that your app is currently in the App Store review process. I would click on "Binary Details" and then click "Reject this Binary" at the top right. This will remove your app from the App Store review process (status will be "Developer Rejected")and you should now be able to edit your Bundle ID and then resubmit for review.

[image: Binary Details]

However, I am assuming your app has never been previously approved. If it has been approved before, I think you need to create an entirely new app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The app is "Waiting for upload". I can't figure out how to upload since i made so much provisioning profiles and stuff like that so as you said i was going to reject this binary to start fresh but there is no "Reject this Binary" Button. Is there a way for me to completely delete the app, delete all the provisioning profiles and start fresh?

Comment: I added a screenshot to my answer. Click on your App icon to view your app details, then click on on "Binary Details" in the top right list to go to the next screen. Then, click on "Reject Binary" at the top right. But are you getting to correct screen but there isnt a "reject binary" because you havent uploaded yet? is that what you are seeing?

Comment: If you cannot reject, then I think you need to email Dev support and ask them to reject this build of the app so you can start over.

Comment: Oh i found the answer, since my app never got approved, it cannot be rejected so there is no "Reject this Binary" button. Either i wait 5-7 months until they delete it automatically or i could email them. I decided to start fresh since it's my first app and i've made a lot of mistakes. Thanks a lot for your time and your answers!

Comment: Sure thing! I hope Apple responds to your request to remove the app from review. They can be slow! But certainly faster than 5-7 months. Good luck with your app. Can you post your app to the thread when it gets approved so I can check it out?

Comment: Sure! I'll do that. Hopefully it will be soon since my app got rejected 3 times already! Thanks again.

Comment: My first app ever just got approved, it's called complete database for Titanfall. It's free so you can check it out but it's a really simple app!

Comment: Cool. I will check it out for sure. I'm still playing Battlefield and haven't picked up Titanfall yet.

Comment: I just rant into this and had a typo in my bundle Id. The menu to edit that (if you have never submitted) is now under More > About this App

Comment: @TimKelly you should submit your comment as an answer as you've hit the nail on the head in about 10 words. Thank you!

Comment: OK @JonnyWhite, thanks, I added as an answer with screen shot.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this is. My app was never previously approved and I can't change the Bundle ID, nor can I remove it from the store. Am I missing something, or is there something just terribly wrong with Apple these days?

Answer (score 15):

The menu to edit the bundle ID (if you have never submitted) is now under **More** > **About this App**

[image]

**7/25/16 update**: Now you can just edit the bundle id under the App Information if you have never <strike>published</strike> uploaded a build:

[image]

Comment: then click on what? The "?" ??

Comment: I wish Apple lovers could see some of the asinine hoops developers have to jump through to publish an app.

Comment: Just to complete the answer for others newbies like me, the IDs can't be edit but can be created and deleted at Developer site ->Member Center->Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles : https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action

Comment: I have no idea what screen this screenshot is from, but it could just be that Apple moved things around again.

Answer (score 8):

I also have the same issue, and have been able to edit this field in past apps. I called Apple support and they said that the issue is; that once Game Centre is turned on for a BundleID it becomes non editable. We even tried turning Game Centre off but to no avail. They told me the options were to use change the BundleID back in Xcode to match the BundleID in iTunesConnect or to change the name of my game in iTunesConnect (to free up that name) and then create a new app/game in iTunesConnect with the newly freed up name and now proper BundleID.

It should be noted that if you change the name to free it up and create a new app/game, you will not be able to delete the old game/app from your iTunesConnect. It will just sit there in limbo.

They said that there is NO way to edit this field once it has been marked is not editable.

This doesn't answer the issue on how to change it but may make it so people stop spending hours trying to change their BundleID.

Cheers

Comment: Hey, this is obviously a very old question but I was facing the same problem today and your answer helped me. As you mentioned it is Game Center that causes this and turning it off will not work by itself. But if you also remove  all the leaderboards and achievements from the features section you can change the bundle ID again. After that you just need to recreate the leaderboards.

Comment: Thanks thought it might be a useful tip when this happens again.

Answer (score 3):

My App hasn't been validated yet, that because on an error on the bundle id.

To edit the bundle id I went to App Information "Edit", and then I've changed (even created a new one)

[image: App Info ->Edit]

[image: Edit or register a new bundle id]

Comment: where is app information in itunes connect. Please help