# Update app bundle ID on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, bundle-identifier

My App is rejected due to a reserve word "**ios**" (com.appname.ios) in bundle ID.Now i want to update bundle ID . Otherwise i have to create a new app with new name ,That can lead an inappropriate name for app .Is there way to update bundle ID after app rejection so that i can update app with creating new one.

Note : My question is some how linked to this question [Can't change bundle ID in itunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851349/cant-change-bundle-id-in-itunes-connect)

But this answer isn't supported in new UI of iTunes connect. So can some one answer this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: it is related to programming , and  submitting app to app store .

Comment: Nope.  It's about Apple's app management system.

Comment: i gave a link that answered for old versions for iTunes connect , But now the UI of iTunes Connect is change and i am not finding a way to do this .

Comment: [This is the solution to your problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26591981/2085916)

Comment: @Ali These options are not available now in ITunes connect

Comment: Then it is non editable once you uploaded a build.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning Mohammad

why don't you create a new project with a more suitable bundle name and copy most of your files from your old project over and onto the new project you have just created.

Or why have you changed your bundle id? if apple accepted it the first time with the old id you used to have, why did you change it to iOS?

Kind Regards,
Ryan

**EDIT:**
I found this answer from someone else asking a similar thing:

*Once u create the Bundle ID,You cannot change in itunes Connect.Only option you can delete and re do Again
Or you can Specify the same Bundle ID in Your Xcode Project*

Comment: this is my first build submitted to apple and got rejected , I can create a new project but that can't create new app in iTunes connect with same name . I want to avoid this new app creation process in iTunes connect

Comment: why don't you just try updating the bundle name and submitting it as an update?

Comment: Thanks , let me try it .

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ yeah no problem :) give it a go and also I have added an edit that might be helpful

Comment: thanks , it is not a complete answer so i can't mark it accepted , but i gave it a up vote because it is nearest possible solution

Comment: @MOHAMMADISHAQ not a problem dude :) did it work for you though?

Comment: I create a new application with a change name itunnes connect and use bundle name same as for old one. –